# unity3d - 403 forbidden error when i try to login

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

I created a website which allows the user to register. Now i have to use that details to login in my unity app. When my website is just using localhost, it is working fine. but now that I have uploaded the website in a web hosting app, I can no longer login and 403 forbidden error is the one showing.

Here's my code:

[image]

[image: Unity Code]

[image]

Comment: You posted your database password along with the address, might wanna change that password immediately.

Comment: Please, post your code as text, not image. It's hard to read and detect problems.